# Canvas over image inside an scrollable div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a `canvas` over an  `image` in a scrollable `div`. Already accomplish the `canvas` over `image` part, but I'm having problems with the scroll.

**This is the `HTML`:**

```
<div id="image-container">
    <canvas></canvas>
    <img id="ori-image" src="{% static "image.jpg" %}" height="550px" alt="screen">
</div>
```

**And this is the`css`**:

```
#image-container {
  position: relative;
}

#image-container > img,
#image-container > canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

This works fine, the problem is if I try to put it in a scrollable `div` wouldn't work.

```
div.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

If I add the previous `CSS` selector to a parent `div` the image disappear.

Comment: You parent container has no dimensions so when you set overflow auto, it goes to 0 height and everything is gone.  Set a height on the div

Comment: @bhmahler fixed, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a height on your scroll div so that it knows when to overflow.  If not, it will just collapse to 0 height with `overflow: auto;`

```css
#image-container {
  position: relative;
}

#image-container > img,
#image-container > canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

div.scroll {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-container" class="scroll">
    <canvas></canvas>
    <img id="ori-image" src="{% static "image.jpg" %}" height="550px" alt="screen">
</div>
```